# Updating a form, updates all records of a particular instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

So I am working on a recipe book rails application. A user can create a recipe, view the recipe, and update the recipe. However, when I update a particular ingredient's quantity (i.e. Pasta "2 Cups" ) it changes all the other recipes that contain pasta to that new quantity ("2 Cups"). I can see in my rails console and server that it recognizes the change and updates, but when I display the view it looks as if it displays the first instance of the ingredient and not the one that I just updated. I have a strong feeling that it is an error with my quantity method in ingredients, but i'm not sure how to fix it.

Recipe Model

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, required: false
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :instructions, presence: true
    validates :cooktime, presence: true

    def self.alphabetize
     self.order(name: :asc)
    end

    def ingredients_attributes=(ingredients_attributes)
      self.ingredients = []
      ingredients_attributes.values.each do |ingredients_attribute|
      if !ingredients_attribute[:name].empty?
          new_ingredient = Ingredient.find_or_create_by(name: 
           ingredients_attribute[:name])
          self.recipe_ingredients.build(ingredient_id: new_ingredient.id, 
          quantity: ingredients_attribute[:quantity])
          end
       end
     end
    end
```

Ingredients Model

```
   class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :recipe_ingredients
      has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

      def self.alphabetize
        self.order(name: :asc)
      end

      def quantity
        recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.find_by(recipe_id: 
         self.recipes.first.id, ingredient_id: self.id)
        recipe_ingredient.quantity
      end
     end
```

Recipe Show, Edit and Update Actions:

```
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @ingredients = @recipe.ingredients.alphabetize
  end

  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
     @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
     if @recipe.user = current_user
       if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        redirect_to @recipe
       else
         render :edit
       end
    end
  end
```

views/recipes/show (ingredients - quantity) listing:

```
  <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient|%>
    <li><%=ingredient.name %> - <%=ingredient.quantity%></li>
  <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the problem area:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord

def quantity
  recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.find_by(recipe_id: 
  self.recipes.first.id, ingredient_id: self.id)
  recipe_ingredient.quantity
end
```

`<%=ingredient.quantity%>` will return the quantity of the first recipe to use the ingredient no matter the recipe. I think you should be accessing the `recipe_ingerdient.quantity` instead.

```
<% @recipe.recipe_ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient|%>
  <li><%=recipe_ingredient.name %> - <%=recipe_ingredient.quantity%></li>
<%end%>
```

as it looks like the quantity for each recipe is saved in the `recipe_ingredient` join table.

Edit: This approach would require adding `delegate :name, to: :ingredient` to `class RecipeIngredient`

Comment: You might consider adding the delegation that allows for `receipt_ingredient.name` to your answer so it's clear to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Just to riff on abax's answer a bit. I think I would do something like:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

  def self.alphabetize
    self.order(name: :asc)
  end

  def quantity_for(recipe)
    recipe_ingredients.where(recipe: recipe).first.quantity
  end

end
```

Which you would use something like:

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient|%>
  <li>
    <%= ingredient.name %> - <%= ingredient.quantity_for(@recipe) %>
  </li>
<%end%>
```

IMO, `ingredient.quantity_for(@recipe)` indicates very clearly what's going on: the `ingredient` is returning the `quantity_for` a particular `@recipe`.

BTW, this:

```
def quantity
  recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.find_by(
    recipe_id: self.recipes.first.id, 
    ingredient_id: self.id
  )
  recipe_ingredient.quantity
end
```

Is all sorts of wrong. In addition to the problem identified by abax, you don't need to do

```
RecipeIngredient.find_by(ingredient_id: self.id)
```

That's why you did `has_many recipe_ingredients`! So that you can simply do:

```
recipe_ingredients.where(recipe: recipe)
```

And, note that when you do associations, you don't have to say `recipe_id: recipe.id`. Rails allows you to simply do `recipe: recipe`. Less typing. Fewer typos.

Finally, this assignment:

```
recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.find_by(...)
```

Isn't necessary. You could just do:

```
RecipeIngredient.find_by(
  recipe:     recipe,
  ingredient: self
).quantity
```

Which, of course, you would never do. Because, as above, it's much nicer to do:

```
recipe_ingredients.where(recipe: recipe).first.quantity
```

Comment: Perhaps my idea of the schema is off. Can you explain your thought process behind the use of `Ingredient#quantity_for` instead of reading directly from the `recipe_ingredients` table which holds the quantity value for that particular recipe? I guess you have to access both models at some point, one for the name and the other for the quantity so maybe it's splitting hairs. Just wondering.

Comment: IMO, you want your view to know as little about your models as possible. Your view, for instance, shouldn't need to know there is a thing called `receipt_ingredient` and that `recipe_ingredient` contains `quantity`. Also, I believe that `recipe_ingredient` doesn't hold the value `name`. So, you can't do `recipe_ingredient.name` as in your solution. You would have to do `recipe_ingredient.ingredient.name`. And now your view needs to know **A LOT** about how your models are organized. By doing `ingredient.quantity_for(@recipe)`, your view needs to know less about how your models are organized.

Comment: I agree with you on the view becoming too complex. I still like the `recipe_ingredient` idea in general and I think I'd address the view concern by sticking with `recipe_ingredient.name` and `delegate :name, to: :ingredient`

Comment: I hear you. And, I do think there is a fair bit of preference involved here. What happens if you later decide to change `ingredient.name` to `ingredient.long_name` (and add `ingredient.short_name`)? In that case, you would have to remember to make changes to your `delegate` directive in `recipe_ingredient`. Personally, I try to go for as little coupling as possible. But, again, I feel that is a matter of personal preference. Your solution works great.

Comment: Great point. I'm definitely still learning when it comes to having a maintenance perspective. Thanks for circling back, I've appreciated the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a more modest goal to start with - just to let users create nested RecipeIngedients:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for(:recipe_ingredients) do |ri| %>
    <%= ri.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= ri.text_field(:quantity) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients
end
```

---

```
def recipe_attributes
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:foo, :bar, recipe_ingredient_attributes: [:ingredient_id, :quantity])
end
```

You can then expand this by using an additional level of nested attributes:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:recipe_ingredients) do |ri| %>
    <div class="recipe-ingredient">
      <%= ri.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %>
      <%= ri.fields_for(:ingredient) |ingredient| %>
        <%= ingredient.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient, reject_if: [:ingredient_exists?, 

  private

  def ingredient_exists?(attributes)
    Ingredient.exists?(name: attributes[:name])
  end

  def ingredient_set?(attributes)
    self.ingredient.nil?
  end
end
```

---

```
def recipe_attributes
  params.require(:recipe)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, 
          recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:ingredient_id, :quantity, { ingredient_attributes: [:name] }]
        )
end
```

But using nested attributes more than one level down usually turns into a real mess since you´re stuffing so much functionality down into a single controller. A better alternative both from the the programming and UX perspective might be to use ajax to setup an autocomplete and create the records on the fly by POST'ing to `/ingredients`.